# WIndows 10 Upgrade Installation Reboots And Does Nothing Further

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit (hoping to "upgrade" to Windows 10 Pro).

In my Windows 10 Installation attempt, I am presented with this window:

[image: Windows Upgrade Dialog]

I select the "Start the upgrade now" button, my computer promptly shuts down and reboots back into Windows 7, putting me back at square one.

Note that this is not the "endless reboot" problem others have reported after their initial installation of Windows 10.

My problem is the initial installation doesn't even get started. It simply reboots my machine exactly as if I had selected "Restart" from the Start menu. There are no error codes presented to me.

Does anyone have an idea of how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Not hopeful but, does Event Viewer show anything?

Comment: Was Windows 7 installed on the PC when you bought it, or have you installed the operating system yourself? Asking because I had a similar problem with my Win 8.1 -> 10 upgrade where the Windows Update method refused to work in a similar way to this where I'd installed the operating system myself.

Comment: @Dave - Where should I look in the Event Viewer? It's a big place.

Comment: @Richard - No, the machine originally came with Vista. I upgraded it. What bugs me is the lack of error message or codes. It just reboots with no indication of the underlying problem.

Comment: Clear the Event Logs via the Event Viewer (Application and System logs at least), then try it again while paying attention to a clock.  After it reboots, look in the Event Viewer for Warning/Error entries from the "last hour".  Read them and try to determine if they're related.

Comment: If you use the Media Creation Tool and choose the "upgrade now" option does it act different?

Comment: @Techie -- DO you know in which section of the Event Log the WIn 10 Installer writes its log messages?

Comment: @Ramhound - If I use the Media Creation Tool I get that wonderful and highly useful, "Something happened" error message.

Comment: I assume Service Pack 1 is installed?

Comment: @Ramhound- Yes, SP1 was installed, long ago.

Comment: @ALL -- Okay, Event log is clean as a whistle. Waiting for the 2.7GB to download and then attempt the install. Thanks to all!!

Comment: Sounds like the installer isn't being launched at reboot due to you having a non-standard boot configuration database.

Comment: @ALL - Believe it or not, the Event Viewer shows no errors related to Win 10 Installer. The machine is not set up for dual boot. I removed my external USB drives as well as Magic Disc. If this doesn't work I'm going to re-install Win 7 and then try the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to get Windows 10 to install. I did three things and I am not sure which one was the trick -- I suspect it was #3:

1. Unplugged all external USB hard drives.
2. Un-installed "Magic Disc".
3. Un-installed "Comodo Programs Manager" (this application monitors and records all installation activity under Windows 7).

Now I am using Win10. Again, I strongly suspect #3 was the item that allowed Win10 to install.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that an antivirus software is blocking the upgrade. Try disabling your antivirus temporarily, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to not use the upgrade option that pops up on the computer.

1. Download the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool
2. Install to USB drive (only 2 options to pick from)
3. Then install Win10 from the USB drive when finished.

That works and fixes this odd reboot loop.